# How to fix "publish-please can't be installed globally" error when I try `npm install firebase-tools -g`

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, frontend, firebase-tools

I am facing an issue recently on my CI server. I always run npm install firebase-tools every time I would want to deploy my codes. However, recently this error prevents it from happenning.

Step to reproduce

1. cd to project folder
2. run `npm install firebase-tools -g`

output

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

> publish-please@5.5.2 preinstall C:\Users\ulala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\publish-please
> node lib/pre-install.js


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!! Starting from v2.0.0 publish-please can't be installed globally.          !!
!! Use local installation instead : 'npm install --save-dev publish-please', !!
!! Or use npx if you do not want to install publish-please as a dependency.  !!
!! (learn more: https://github.com/inikulin/publish-please#readme).          !!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! publish-please@5.5.2 preinstall: `node lib/pre-install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the publish-please@5.5.2 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Edit: here is my package.json. I don't install firebase-tools in my project.

package.json

```json
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "test": "ng test",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "npm run lint"
        }
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~10.0.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^10.1.1",
        "@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
        "@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32",
        "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
        "@angular/material": "^10.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
        "@ngrx/effects": "^10.0.0-beta.0",
        "@ngrx/entity": "^10.0.0-beta.0",
        "@ngrx/router-store": "^10.0.0-beta.0",
        "@ngrx/store": "^10.0.0-beta.0",
        "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^10.0.0-beta.0",
        "@types/uuid": "^8.0.0",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
        "compressorjs": "^1.0.6",
        "emailjs-com": "^2.4.1",
        "firebase": "^7.15.5",
        "ng2-charts": "^2.4.1",
        "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "uuid": "^8.2.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/architect": ">= 0.900 < 0.1100",
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.8",
        "@angular/cli": "~10.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.0-next.1",
        "firebase-tools": "^8.0.0",
        "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
        "husky": "^4.2.5",
        "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
        "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "karma": "~5.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "open": "^7.0.3",
        "prettier": "^2.0.5",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
        "tslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.3.0",
        "typescript": "~3.9.5"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/skilio/client-web-app-2.0.git"
    },
    "author": "Dody",
    "license": "ISC",
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://gitlab.com/skilio/client-web-app-2.0/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://gitlab.com/skilio/client-web-app-2.0#readme"
}
```

Comment: Hey can you show me your package.js?

Comment: hi, I got same problem with publish-please package. btw, in my CI/CD, I didn't use npm but use this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#mac-linux-auto-script

Comment: @development-ninja I pasted my package.json

Comment: Hey this error is recently happening. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2907
Firebase support will help on it. While it is being solved you will need to manage version of your os to fix

Comment: @development-ninja thanks for the clarification! Ill close this question!

Answer (score 1):

As of about an hour ago (as of this writing) a fix has been published to the [`cli-table`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli-table) dependency of `firebase-tools`. If you try `npm install -g firebase-tools` now, it should work.

In other words, you weren't doing anything wrong. This was a temporary breakage in a dependency of `firebase-tools` that existed for a few hours.